# How to pass value from change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have Idea how to pass a value from change function, for example i have function like this :

```
$('pilihan').change(function(){
var amount = $('#pilihan option:selected').val();
var result = amount*12; });
```

I want pass value of "result" variable to other function just like this :

```
function add() {
var lastresult = result+56;
$('#jumlah').text(lastresult);
```

If I do this, then variable "result" in add function doesn't has value.

So, how to pass result variable value from change function to other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call add method from the change event function, just like as below:

```
$('pilihan').change(function(){
var amount = $('#pilihan option:selected').val();
var result = amount*12;
```

> add(result);

```
});


function add(result) {
var lastresult = result+56;
$('#jumlah').text(lastresult);
```

You can even combine both function:

```
$('pilihan').change(function(){
var amount = parseFloat($('#pilihan option:selected').val()) * 12 + 56;
$('#jumlah').text(amount);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly when I add result in functio add like this -> function add(result). Thanks!

Comment: sure, I don't understand why you have two functions to though; I have given you an alternative that you may want to see too.

Comment: I have 3 on change function so I want add function to add all value. But when i try to use function add(result, result2, result3) from 3 on change value why it returned NaN?

Comment: @tzudin you got to call it separately like add(result) + add(result2) or otherwise chagne it to add(result, result2 ... )

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to call function with parameter.

```
$('pilihan').change(function(){
   var amount = $('#pilihan option:selected').val();
   var result = amount*12; 
   add(result);
});

function add(result) {
   var lastresult = result+56;
   $('#jumlah').text(lastresult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var result;
$('pilihan').change(function(){
var amount = $('#pilihan option:selected').val();
result= amount*12; });
I want pass value of "result" variable to other function just like this :

function add(result) {
var lastresult = result+56;
$('#jumlah').text(lastresult);
```